# Decrypting using GnuPG from within SQL Server Job

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, encryption, gnupg

I have a SQL Server job that includes a step that runs a windows batch script (.bat). Within the batch code there is a line that calls the command line instruction to decrypt a file using GnuPG.

Running the batch file manually (double-clicking from the Windows GUI) all of the commands run fine including the decryption instruction. I get the same results when the batch file is run using a programmed task via the Windows Task Scheduler.

When running the batch file through SQL Server and the SQL Server Agent, when it comes to the line where the decryption instruction is called it throws an error.

The log file for that particular SQL Job step contains the following output:

```
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "[myusername]".
Authenticating with public key "[configured public key]".
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] [myusername]f@[sftpServerIP]
extract_CES_SAE_v3_[myusername]_[datestring].txt.pgp |           1 KB |    0.0 KB/s | binary | 100%
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID [RSAKeyIDNumber]
gpg: public key decryption failed: No secret key
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

*Certain fields redacted for security*

I've run out of ideas on how to get it to work when running it from a SQL Server job.

Has anyone else come across something like this and been able to solve it? I've looked online for this very issue but can't seem to find any instance where the decryption instruction is run from within SQL Server, and the majority of cases documented with a similar error are from within a Linux environment instead of Windows.

The batch script is in charge of the following steps:

1. Scans a local directory for the most recently downloaded/generated file; saves filename to a variable.
2. Connects to an SFTP directory via WinSCP to download the most recently generated file over 1kb in size (encrypted).
3. Re-scans the directory to ensure that a file has, in fact, been downloaded and saves the most recently downloaded/generated filename to a new variable.
4. Both variables are compared, if their contents are the same the script exits, if not it continues.
5. Decryption of the most recently downloaded file into a readable .txt and placed into separate folder.
6. Copy made of the newly decrypted .txt and renamed to append date-time into the filename.
7. Original decrypted file is copied to a directory where it is then processed by the rest of the SQL Server job.

Like I mentioned, the decryption is carried out with no errors when the batch file is run from the Windows GUI or through the Task Scheduler, but throws the "no secret key" error when running from the SQL Server job.

The line in question within the script that decrypts the file is the following:
`gpg --batch --yes --output C:\[AppDirectory]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[myusername].txt --decrypt %LAST%`

The %LAST% variable contains the filename to be decrypted and the output directs it where to store the decrypted file. Running this specific line through the command prompt, specifying the name of the file instead of the variable, works with no issues. Running a batch file from the Windows GUI with the filename stored in a variable works with no issues, as does running it from the Task Scheduler.

*** EDIT TO INCLUDE THE .BAT CODE ***

```
@echo off

cd C:\[AppPath]\in\

if exist C:\[AppPath]\in\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt (
  cd C:\[AppPath]\automation\
  echo -1 > C:\[AppPath]\automation\output.txt
  powershell "C:\[AppPath]\automation\EmailProcessingError.ps1"
  exit /b -1
)

cd C:\[AppPath]\automation\downloaded\

for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\[AppPath]\automation\downloaded\" /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set PGPFILE=%%i
echo ULTIMO ARCHIVO ANTES DE DESCARGA = %PGPFILE% > C:\[AppPath]\automation\log\automation_log.txt

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\[AppPath]\automation\log\WinSCP_.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://[sftpUserName]@[sftpIpAddress]/ -hostkey=""[hostKeyInfo]"" -privatekey=""C:\[KeyDirectory]\FTP\[PrivateKeyName].ppk"" -rawsettings AgentFwd=1" ^
    "get -latest -filemask=*>1K /out/extract_CES* C:\[AppPath]\automation\downloaded\" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%

for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\[AppPath]\automation\downloaded\" /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo ULTIMO ARCHIVO DESPUES DE DESCARGA = %LAST% >> C:\[AppPath]\automation\log\automation_log.txt

if %LAST%==%PGPFILE% (
  cd C:\[AppPath]\automation\
  echo 1 > C:\[AppPath]\automation\output.txt
  powershell "C:\[AppPath]\automation\EmailNoNewFile.ps1"
  exit /b 1
) else (
  gpg --batch --yes --output C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt --decrypt %LAST%
)

cd C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted

if exist C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt (
  copy /y C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName]_1.txt
) else (
  echo ERROR EN DESENCRIPTACION DEL ARCHIVO >> C:\[AppPath]\automation\log\automation_log.txt
  exit /b -1
)

rem copy /y C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName]_1.txt

set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%

rename extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName]_1.txt extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName]_%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%.txt

robocopy C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\ C:\[AppPath]\in extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt

del C:\[AppPath]\automation\decrypted\extract_CES_SAE_v3_[sftpUserName].txt

powershell "C:\[AppPath]\automation\EmailNewFile.ps1"
echo 0 > C:\[AppPath]\automation\output.txt
```

*** EDIT 2 TO INCLUDE EVIDENCE OF JOB RUNNING UNDER AD USER ***
[SQL Job running as AD User; Server and Domain redacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0RwK.png)

Comment: I'm guessing it's about the "current" directories, or current user running the job. Perhaps the decryption stuff is bound to user folders (usually the case with .ssh etc)? So the sql server user doesn't have access to same keys as regular one. ALso, make sure the bat script actually does a CD <your dir> so nothing fancy is going on with current dirs

Comment: Yeah, whenever anything has to be done in a directory I've coded de "cd [Path]" to the specific directory where the task will be done (copy, rename, etc.).

As far as the user permissions, the specific task is assigned to be run using my AD profile, which has admin-rights across the domain and for all directories involved. This is also why I can't figure out why it works outside of SQL Server, but when configured to run under my AD profile within SQL server it still throws those errors.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL Agent Job runs as your account? I remember it being quite complicated to setup correctly?

Comment: Yes. Verified by looking up the job history and the "executed as user" field. I did have to set up credentials for my account to run from SQL Server, but it is a recognized user log-in with Windows Authentication and perimissions. The rest of the jobs on the server have been running under the SQL Server service account that's been configured to run those jobs, which is a service account also registered in the domain with certain permissions.